# Does Apple's Design Language have a name?

Tags: ios, macos, user-interface, user-experience

Google has `Material Design`, Microsoft has `Fluent` and (unofficially) `Metro`.

About two decades ago, the User Interface for Mac OS X was called `Aqua` but I do not see this term used in practice as much anymore (it does not even have a StackOverflow tag like `Material Design` and `Microsoft-Metro` have).

Is there a specific name (official or unofficial) for the design language across Apple platforms?

Comment: Its just called `UIKit`

Comment: @WilliamGP: But doesn't UIKit only work on iOS (which would exclude the term from being used on macOS, watchOS, and tvOS)?

Comment: Oh ok. I see your point. (`UIKit` is also for tvOS) but I guess there is not an actual name for their design philosophy like Google and Microsoft have - they do put out their guidelines for design though here - https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm not entirely sure it's 100% analogous to Material Design, I'd say the term you're looking for is [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/).

Comment: Thank you for your post. Do you know if anyone colloquially refers to the Human Interface Guidelines as "San Fransisco Design Language" as its official font is "San Fransisco"?

Comment: I've never heard that, no. Just Human Interface Guidelines or HIG.

Answer (score 1):

On [this](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/) page in Apple's website you'll find the phrase "iOS design language". The macOS design language for a long time was Aqua but since Mojave, [Aqua](https://apple.fandom.com/wiki/Aqua) is treated like a legacy term [in the SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

Flutter calls iOS design ["Cupertino"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino), am not sure how relevant that is however, there should be a reason that Google developers has named that set of components Cupertino, other than the fact Apple Park is located in Cupertino, California (maybe private shared documentation?); or maybe not as it is referred iOS design language in rest of the documentation and they just wanted some name usable in code. Brought the finding here as I liked Wikipedia to have an entry for the design language about iOS design in addition to [Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) but I feel there is lack of documentation for the topic so am requesting people here to link related content in preparation of building such entry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , in fact i've just had a uni class about flutter, where they call Apple's  "User Experience", Cupertino.